# what is the equivalent of text-align: -webkit-center; in (IE)Trident, (Firefox)Gecko, (Opera)Presto?

Tags: html, css

i want no know is their any css property which is equivalent to webkit css property.
in my case

```
text-align: -webkit-center;
```

Comment: `text-align: center` for all browsers and you don't need hacks

Comment: In chrome, if I use text-align:-webkit-center my table centers perfectly within the div, but if I use text-align:center, it does not.  Clearly there is a difference between the two.

Comment: For block elements you need to use "margin: 0 auto". text-align is used to center inline and inline-block elements. -webkit-center is used to mimic the old html-align-attribute ans should not be used in production.